# vaadin push works on tomcat 7 but not on tomcat 8

Tags: tomcat, intellij-idea, websocket, vaadin, vaadin7

i wrote a vaadin project for tomcat 7 and it works locally. after migrating it to tomcat 8 i can not start the page anymore because i get the message:

> HTTP Status 500 - com.vaadin.server.ServiceException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Push is not available. See previous log messages for more information.

the first exception shows the following line:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to createclass org.atmosphere.container.JettyServlet30AsyncSupportWithWebSocket

i uses following dependencies in my pom file for both tomcat versions

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.java-websocket</groupId>
        <artifactId>Java-WebSocket</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
        <artifactId>vaadin-push</artifactId>
        <version>7.3.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
        <artifactId>vaadin-client</artifactId>
        <version>7.3.10</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

this neither worked when i just changed the tomcatversion from 7 to 8 with my existing project, nor when i created a new project in intellij and copied the old java classes and ressources to the new created project.

Answer (score 0):

after i removed all jars starting with "jetty" inside the WEB-INF/lib folder the problem was solved.

Comment: If you use Maven, all dependencies should be managed by Maven which means that you should not have any jar files on your project directories.